# Can you use wildcards with Vim's open file under cursor feature?

Tags: vim

I move a lot between files from within Vim by highlighting a path and pressing the keys `gf`. I'm creating a makeshift Vim wiki for note-taking purposes, and I wanted to write only the beginning of a filename to be used as a link, because the way I have it, each filename begins with a unique identifier and so there would be no other matches, like so:

`/notes/20190712*`

I'm wondering if a simple asterisk wildcard could suffice for Vim to properly follow the incomplete filename, like how it autocompletes when `:edit`,`:find` or similar commands.

Vim's help alludes to some sort of expansion that takes place if it can't find a file, using something called `includeexpr`:

> ...used for the gf command if an unmodified file name can't be found. 
>   Allows doing "gf" on the name after an 'include' statement.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `like how it autocompletes when :edit,:find` Then just remap it to `:find` the WORD under cursor.

Comment: Will the remaining part of the file name, the one one that you exclude, remain the same for all files? My guess is yes as it is likely your file extension. If it's indeed yes, you could use [suffixesadd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'suffixesadd') for supplying this common suffix.

Comment: The full file name that I'm trying to get vim to follow is something like `20190712_name_of_note.md`, so it'd be more than just the extension that needs to be filled in. Matt, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I may have mislead you with my comparison to those commands. The goal being not for the full filename to be expanded in the document, but simply for Vim on the back end to figure out where to go and to take me to that file.